# Error: DataSource is not set for this entity in node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, google-cloud-platform

We get this error in our backend workload and DB connection fails 2024-02-08 10:06:58.194 IST
Error: DataSource is not set for this entity.     at NarApplication.getRepository (/app/node_modules/typeorm/repository/BaseEntity.js:78:19)     at NarApplication.find (/app/node_modules/typeorm/repository/BaseEntity.js:239:21)     at /app/dist/app/controllers/applications.js:85:71     at Generator.next ()     at /app/dist/app/controllers/applications.js:31:71     at new Promise ()     at __awaiter (/app/dist/app/controllers/applications.js:27:12)     at getApplicationsByNarId (/app/dist/app/controllers/applications.js:83:46)     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)     at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)

Latest module of type ORM used is 0.3.17 and above

Setup used for backend is on GKE->Cloud sql proxy is connecting to on premise DB and fetching data into cloud postgre sql,node.js is used to develop the application code.

Please help to rectify the issue

Application is able to make connection locally but its not working on GKE container.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.